# PRISMA: How can i select only first string from string array

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I'm looking for solution to taking exact element of String Array in Prisma ORM, in my situation, I want to take only first element of paragraphs array to render short article description on the front.

Thats my article model

```
model articles {
  id         BigInt   @id @default(autoincrement())
  articleId  Int      @unique
  scrapedAt  DateTime @default(now())
  timeString String
  time       BigInt
  title      String
  url        String
  img        String
  paragraphs String[]
}
```

Comment: articles. paragraphs.length?articles. paragraph[0]:null, just need to make sure that articles has elements and take the first one

Comment: I know how to do it in js, I asked mainly about the prisma. I am curious if it can be done at the query level

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we create articles like the code below

```
const result = await prisma.articles.create({
  data:{
  articleId: 1,
  timeString: "25082022",
  time:       25082022,
  title:      "First Article title",
  url:        "First Url",
  img:       "Image URL",
  paragraphs: ["First Paragraph for article", "second paragraph"]
  }
})
```

Then we can query for the paragraphs and pick the first one from the result set

```
const result = await prisma.articles.findFirst({
  where:{
    id: 1n
  },
  select:{
    paragraphs: true
  }
})
console.log(result.paragraphs[0])
```

The query returns the result in this form

```
{ paragraphs: [ 'First Paragrah for article', 'second paragraph' ] }
```

Then the result of logging `result.paragraphs[0]` is

Output

```
First Paragraph for article
```